# Python IndexError : list assignment index out of range

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def trap(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
        n = len(height)
        mxl = []
        mxr = []
        mxl.append(height[0])
        for i in range(1,n):
            mxl[i] = max(mxl[i-1],height[i])
```

Line 8 gives Index error. Is it wrong way to assign value in a list at particular index?

Comment: `mxl[i]` is trying to assign to an index that doesn't exists. Use `mxl.append` instead.

Comment: Yes. You are assigning `mxl[i]` when `i==1`. At this point `mxl` only has one element.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
class Solution:
    def trap(self, height: list[int]) -> int:
        n = len(height)
        mxl = []
        mxr = []
        for item in height:
            mxl.append(item)
        for i in range(1, n):
            mxl[i] = max(mxl[i - 1], height[i])
```

Comment: Why defining `mxr` when it's not being put to any use?

Comment: Why to add items to `mxl` just to override them later? Why not just `mxl.append(max(mxl[i - 1], height[i]))`?

Comment: I just wanted to fix the code without making any major changes. And I think the person who asked the question was trying to solve a leetcode problem

Answer (score 0):

By the way, [np.maximum.accumulate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html) is the fastest (and reliable) way of doing what you are trying to achieve here

```py
mxl = np.maximum.accumulate(height)
```